# Form Validate and using Submit Handler with Ajax not working on Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code that calls when you hit the review button, but when on mobile the loader gif just keeps loading and does not ring back an data from the ajax call, but when i try this on pc browser it works fine.

```
function sendReview() {
    alert('a');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: GetDomain() + "SendReview",
        data: { name: $("#name").val().trim(), email: $("#email").val().trim(), pid: GetParameterByName("id"), review: $("#review").val().trim(), rating: ($(".starsel").index() + 1) },
        success: function (result) {

            alert('b');

            var html = result.html;
            var items = $(".reviewscon").children().length;

            if (items < 5) {
                $(".reviewscon").prepend(html);
            } else {
                $(".reviewscon").prepend(html);
                $(".reviewscon").children().get(items - 1).remove();
            }


            starIndexHit = 0;

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.message);
        }
    });
}

$("form[name='reivew']").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
        // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
        // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
        // on the right side
        name: "required",
        review: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            // Specify that email should be validated
            // by the built-in "email" rule
            email: true
        },
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your name",
        review: "Please enter a review",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        sendReview();
        $("#name").val("");
        $("#email").val("");
        $("#review").val("");
        $(".star").css("color", "#000000");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Once the review button is hit no data retrieved from the server, i tried on pc and works fine not sure wh it does not work for mobile.

```
<form name="reivew">
                        <div class="reviewcontent" style="width:50%;float:left;padding:15px;">


                            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0">
                                <div class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
                                    <label for="title">Name</label>
                                    <input maxlength="50" required type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" aria-describedby="nameHelp" style="width:100%;max-width:none;margin-bottom: 5px;" placeholder="Enter Name">
                                    <small id="nameHelp" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:3px;" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your name.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0">
                                <div class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input maxlength="50" required type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" style="width:100%;max-width:none;margin-bottom: 5px;" placeholder="Enter Email">
                                    <small id="emailHelp" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:3px;" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your email.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:15px;padding-left:0px;">
                                <i style="font-size:22px;color:#000000;" class="fa fa-star star"></i>
                                <i style="font-size:22px;color:#000000;" class="fa fa-star star"></i>
                                <i style="font-size:22px;color:#000000;" class="fa fa-star star"></i>
                                <i style="font-size:22px;color:#000000;" class="fa fa-star star"></i>
                                <i style="font-size:22px;color:#000000;" class="fa fa-star star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <small id="ratingHelp" style="padding-bottom:15px;margin-top:10px;margin-left:3px;" class="form-text text-muted">Give the item a rating.</small>


                            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0">
                                <div class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
                                    <label for="review">Review</label>
                                    <div style="border-radius: 4px;border: 1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                        <textarea maxlength="500" required name="review" class="form-control" id="review" aria-describedby="revHelp" placeholder="Enter Review" style="border:none;max-width:none;width:100%"></textarea>
                                        <div style="float:right;padding:8px;">0/500</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <small id="revHelp" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:3px;" class="form-text text-muted">Enter a review.</small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:10px;">


                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Review</button>

                            </div>




                            <p><i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="padding-right:8px;font-size:16px;"></i>Only give a review if you have had experiences with this item, you do not need to sign in to give a review.</p>


                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Does GetDomain()  return the proper url?

Comment: Yes it does, i tested this on my vps server on my pc and worked fine

Comment: the domain is correct, not sure why its working on pc n not mobile

Comment: @Grumpy: it just does a window.location.hostname with the 'http'

Comment: um, it could be that its should be https